# Exel changed equations into illegible text

Tags: microsoft-excel

Heloo,

1. I created graphical equations in Excel 2013.
2. I edited the document in Excel 2007.
3. I edited the same document in Excel 2013. No more graphical equations.

How can I recover graphical equations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean Liner Equation ?

Comment: I want to have equations in this form  http://tnij.at/graphicalequation . I have this way: g_rz=g_n− c_1 " ="

Comment: Better you link the cell with Text box, check the procedure now I'm posting as Answer. This will help you lot.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

*To get rid from the problem, better you create the New Equation and follow 
 below written steps to link it with the Text box.*

- Insert a Text Box.
- Click the Text box to which you want to link the cell contents(your
  Equation).
- In the formula bar, type an equal sign and click the cell that
  contains the equation that you want to link to Text box.
- Finish with ENTER.

*The contents of the cell will display in the text box.*

**NB:** You can also use the cell reference, for example, `=Sheet1!A2`.

**Edited on OP's Demand:**

*You can use this VBA code to link as many Cells to Text Box.*

```
Private Sub Linl_to_Textbox()

Dim Newshp As Shape
Dim Newtbx As TextBox

Set Newshp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox (msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 200, 200, 150, 150)

Set Newtbx = Newshp.OLEFormat.Object
Newtbx.Formula = "$A$1"

End Sub
```

**NB:**

- 200, 200, 150, 150 are dimensions of the Text box which can be
  altered.
- In Cell A1, you need to write this kind of 
  equitation,`=E2&CHAR(10)&E4&CHAR(10)&E6`

*Where E2 to E6 has Graphic Equitations.*

Comment: I have about 30 fields to change. Is there anyway to automate this?

Comment: Honestly I've never tried any such automate procedure (the VBA), so that unable to suggest you instant solution, the VBA Code. Better give me some time to explore my back files and then only I can suggest you. But let me say, Yes it's possible to automate the procedure.

Comment: Meanwhile you write me, what are the locations (Cell position) of all 30 fields?

Comment: Would be it possible to detect fields with such code? Assume all boxes need "translation".

Comment: Almost every move is possible with VBA :-)

Comment: I tried to use method described in your Answer... But I obtain following windows as response of Excel: ,,There is problem ith formula. Defined name or reference to range was not found".

Comment: Check, I've  edited the answer and included the VBA code lines to add range of cells to Text box.

Comment: What formula you have written,,? use proper composition all I've suggested you are working properly.